# Exclude files from vscode C++ debug step into?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to exclude certain files from being stepped in to in the vscode C++ debugger? I'm using gdb for debugging.

My executable is built and run remotely in a Docker container, and the host environment for VSCode does not have the standard header files instead for the Docker environment.

In particular, it's trying to step into STL code, which I'd rather exclude anyway.

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

To skip files while debugging with gdb in VSCode, one could add the following section to `setupCommands` of launch.json :

```
 "setupCommands": [
                      {
                        "description": "Skip library files",
                        "text": "-interpreter-exec console \"skip -gfi **/bits/*.h\""
                      }  
                  ],
```

This is going to skip all header files in all folders named `bits`.  Similarly, one could type `-exec skip -gfi **/bits/*.h` in VSCode debug console.

Comment: Exactly what I searched. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can skip certain files from being stepped in. See documentation for [skip](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Skipping-Over-Functions-and-Files.html):

```
-file file
-fi file

    Functions in file will be skipped over when stepping.
-gfile file-glob-pattern
-gfi file-glob-pattern

    Functions in files matching file-glob-pattern will be skipped over when stepping.

    (gdb) skip -gfi utils/*.c
```