# How do I skip external code when debugging in VS Code

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

When debugging in **vscode** I'd like to make some "blackboxing" and do not enter into code I didn't write. How can I do this?

Comment: Did we collectively stop calling it 'blackboxing' as of 2023 because of racial injustice? Seems like the word 'blackbox' isn't used in any of the developer tools at this point.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

In your launch or attach debug task you can enter a

> "skipfiles"

option which is

> "An array of file or folder names, or path globs, to skip when debugging."

For example, from [skipping node internals during debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_skipping-uninteresting-code)

```
"skipFiles": [
  "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**/*.js",
  "${workspaceFolder}/yourLibToSkip/**/*.js"
]
```

Also, there is a "magic reference" to the built-in core node modules you can use:

```
"skipFiles": [
  "<node_internals>/**/*.js"
]
```

Comment: could you kindly provide some example, I still cannot prevent entering  to different dependencies folders inside of  "node_modules" folder (i.e. ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/...), when debugging . part of launch task is `"skipFiles":"[./node_modules/**]"`

Comment: @d2048 See my edits to the answer and the included link.

Comment: This doesn't work for flutter. Can you please show us the full example for flutter please? This looks like for javascript

Comment: That "magic reference" doesn't work. I've downloaded VSCode today, debugged a TypeScript project, and am still ending up in `async_hooks.js`.

Comment: Did you try the ` "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/**/*.js"` version as well?

Comment: Although `"skipFiles":["<node_internals>/**"]` works for debug sessions which are NOT attached, it doesn't seem to work in case of attaching a process.

Comment: Then how to add automatically generated files into skipfiles?

Comment: Sometimes it needs to specify the file to ignore without 'js' extension 
example:

"<node_internals>/internal/async_hooks",
        "<node_internals>/internal/inspector_async_hook"

Answer (score 14):

I was confused on where to put the setting, so just in case, if you want to skip both `node_modules` deps and `node_internals` files, your `.vscode/launch.json` file should look something like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug Tests",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            ...
            "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**", "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**/*.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This was the answer that worked for me debugging a ReactJS app using Chrome on Windows.

Comment: I was trying with lots of other answers to this question and none of them worked. Turns out my problem was that I had skipFiles as a sibling to configurations instead of as a child. This fixed it for me. Thanks!

Comment: thank you for showing me exactly where to place `skipFiles` in the file. The other refs don't explain this.

Answer (score 3):

Only this worked for me.

```json
"debug.javascript.terminalOptions": {
    "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For flutter apps, add to your user settings the following:

```
"debugExternalPackageLibraries": false,
"dart.debugSdkLibraries": false,
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to amplify on Mauro Aguilar's correct answer, here are the complete contents of my launch.json file.  Note that I am debugging a ReactJS app (circa 2021) with VS Code 1.60.2 on Windows 10 using Chrome v.94.  If you're using a Linux machine or a Mac, YMMV.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**/*.js", "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**/*.js"]
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Typescript built with Webpack, I had to put the exclusions in launch.json - putting them in settings.json/terminalOptions had no effect.

Also, I had to exclude the pattern of the **generated files**, not the source files.  In my case it looks like:

```
"skipFiles": [
    "<node_internals>/**",
    "**/vendors-*",
],
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my launch.json file (it works for me):

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "edge",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Edge against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:4200",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "skipFiles": [
              "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**/*.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I've needed to add both types of skip file entries,

```
  "skipFiles": [
    "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**/*.js",
    "<node_internals>/**"
  ],
```

This seems to have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the language/debug-support extension. VS Code does not have a generalized way to do this because languages differ in the ways that they describe programs in source and object/binary formats, and in the ways that their backing debug tooling support skipping things in debugging.

- For `node` launch configurations, use the [`skipFiles`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/blob/main/OPTIONS.md#skipfiles-1) property of the launch config. Related user documentation can be found at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_skipping-uninteresting-code.

  You can also use the `skipFiles` property of the `debug.javascript.terminalOptions` setting for [auto-attach](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_auto-attach) and [JS debug terminals](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_javascript-debug-terminal).
- For Python debugging, use the [`justMyCode`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_justmycode) property of the launch configuration. See also [Visual Studio Code - Python debugging - How to step into external functions/packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53594900/11107541). There's also a `debugpy.debugJustMyCode` contributed by the debugpy extension.
- For Jupyter notebook debugging, use the `jupyter.debugJustMyCode` setting. See also [How to debug external libraries in vscode-jupyter cell debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64842432/11107541).
- For Java debugging with the [vscode-java-debug extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-debug), use the `java.debug.settings.stepping.skipClasses` [user setting](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-debug#user-settings). It takes an array of patterns and supports special values like `$JDK`, `$Libraries`, and `java.lang.ClassLoader`, and also supports wildcards.
- For C/C++ when using a debugger like GDB with the `cppdbg` launch config type, use [GDB's `skip` command](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/Skipping-Over-Functions-and-Files.html) in the `setupCommands` property of the launch config. See also [Exclude files from vscode C++ debug step into?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42782502/11107541), [Tell gdb to skip standard files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5676241/11107541), and [GDB C++ How to Stop Stepping Inside Standard Libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61866191/11107541).
- C# debugging [supports `justMyCode`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/csharp/debugger-settings#_just-my-code) in launch configs via the `justMyCode` property, and in settings via the `csharp.debug.justMyCode` setting.
- For Flutter/Dart, use the `dart.debugSdkLibraries` and `dart.debugExternalPackageLibraries` settings.
- For Go, I don't know. But you can at least use [the `go.delveConfig` setting](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/settings.md#godelveconfig)'s `hideSystemGoroutines` to hide system goroutines from the call-stack view.

Comment: Normally I'd vote to close such a question as lacking focus. But people on meta have gotten cross at me for doing that on well-established questions... Also, I have no idea what to do about https://stackoverflow.com/q/52980448/11107541, which seems to have been interpreted by the community just as broadly despite being about C#.