# When debugging JavaScript within Visual Studio Code and ESlint, is it possible to turn off the default of stepping into <node_internals>?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint, eslintignore

When debugging JavaScript in Visual Studio Code using ESlint, most of the files it tries to step into are node_internals, eg: module.js, bootstrap_node.js util.js etc. You can manually 'Toggle skipping this file' to skip them but it doesn't remember your selection. Is there a way in settings to ignore all of the node_internals files, or need to manually add them all to an ignore list?

Comment: Did you look at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_skipping-uninteresting-code-node-chrome (skipFiles and node_internals)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I skip external code when debugging in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47556495/how-do-i-skip-external-code-when-debugging-in-vs-code)

Comment: I've voted up the skipFiles thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for. The external code question is slightly different from node_internals but yes agree solved by the same docs

Comment: There are two methods, either add a local debug config when in the folder you are debugging and use the skipFiles as below, or set a user default: from preferences, settings and type launch, select 'edit in settings.json'  and include in there: `"launch": {
        "configurations": [
            {
                "type": "node",
                "request": "launch",
                "name": "Skip Node Internals",
                "program": "${file}",
                "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**/*.js"]
                }
              ],
        "compounds": []
      }`