# Visual Studio Code - Python debugging - How to step into external functions/packages?

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

In a Python project, how do you tell the built-in VSCode debugger to step into the code of functions from other libraries on execution?

I know it is possible for functions implemented in standard libraries by adding a

```
"debugOptions": ["DebugStdLib"]
```

to your configuration in *launch.json* as specified [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging), however it does not seem to be possible to force the debugger to step into the code of non-standard modules, such as the ones you have written yourself and imported into the current file.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

In order to improve the accepted answer by John Smith, it is worth mentioning that now the option has been renamed again. The new option is

```
"justMyCode": false
```

and as per the documentation

> When omitted or set to True (the default), restricts debugging to
>   user-written code only. Set to False to also enable debugging of
>   standard library functions.

Comment: For me '"justMyCode": false' worked to put breakpoint and move inside celery's source code.

Comment: For unittest, you may also need `"request": "test",`. [doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing#_debug-tests)

Comment: Why-o-why can't this be the default... :-(

Comment: What about debugging non-standard library functions, i.e., functions inside external libraries installed with pip?

Comment: Where to put this?

Comment: @JoeHuang https://stackoverflow.com/a/68899588/3757063

Comment: @CGFoX that is the purpose of `justMyCode`. It allows you to debug also external libraries (downloaded via pip for example).

Comment: if you like random history, see also https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/8146

Comment: Did not work for me in the default `Python: Current File` debug configuration. I had to create a separate debug configuration with `"justMyCode": false` to get it to work.

Comment: @huang: in launch.json, which can be created the first time you launch debugging.

Answer (score 27):

This is done by customising your debugger.

If you haven't already, you need to initialise the debugger customisation. You can do this by opening the debugger section in the side bar and selecting `create a launch.json file`.

Once this is done, a `launch.json` file will be created in a `.vscode` folder in your workspace.

Edit this file. It will look something like this:

```
{
    ...,
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

Add `"justMyCode": false` to the `"Python: Current File"` configuration, like this:

```
{
    ...,
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": false
        }
    ]
}
```

True as of Visual Studio Code version 1.59.0.

Reference:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging

Answer (score 7):

A debugger configuration with

```
"debugOptions": ["DebugStdLib"]
```

added in *launch.json* in fact **will step into user-defined and pip-installed modules**, contrary to what's written in the main question.

Comment: Why it did not work a couple of times at first, I do not know.

Comment: `"debugOptions"` has been removed as an option from config file. 


Instead use  `"debugStdLib": true`

Comment: As the other answer suggests the new option is now [justMyCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_justmycode)

Answer (score 5):

The configurations in launch.json file as follows work for me.

```
    "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "test",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "justMyCode": false,
        "purpose": ["debug-in-terminal"]
    }
]
```

Comment: Thank you for adding "purpose".  (hey that reads kinda funny)
Without purpose the just my code didn't allow step.

Answer (score 4):

Most of the time, I debug unit tests rather than the running application.

If that is also the case on your side and you use:

- Visual Studio Code
- pytest
- The **Python Test Explorer for Visual Studio Code** (A test runner extension (adds a debug menu and provided debug buttons above tests directly in the IDE)) https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LittleFoxTeam.vscode-python-test-adapter

Then use the following **launch.json** as mentionned in the plugin page:

```
    {
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
            {
                "name": "Debug test",
                "type": "python",
                "request": "attach",
                "console": "externalTerminal",
                "justMyCode": false,
                "stopOnEntry": true,
                "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env.test",
                "purpose": ["debug-test"]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: My hero! Strangely stops once in tests/__init__.py every time, but otherwise works perfectly. I removed the externalTerminal line.

Comment: Just put "stopOnEntry" to false to prevent this behaviour

Comment: Hi. Can I do this on a default test explorer?

Comment: Not sure, this answer has been determined by reading the doc of the specific test explorer (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LittleFoxTeam.vscode-python-test-adapter).

For other test explorer, you either need to try or read the doc related to your tool.

Comment: @Selva I added an answer with some clarification.

Answer (score 4):

For those using the standard VSCode Debugger, a little more clarification on how to configure this in VS Code might be needed

#### Create Your Debugger Configuration As Follows

Open up your `.vscode/launch.json`

Add a configuration `{}` to the configurations list:

```json
"configurations": []
```

This one will be recognized by the built-in VSCode Debugger:

```json
{
  "name": "Python: Debug Tests",
  "type": "python",
  "request": "launch",
  "program": "${file}",
  "purpose": ["debug-test"],
  "console": "integratedTerminal",
  "justMyCode": false
}
```

Key points:

1. `purpose` should be set to ["debug-test"]
2. `"justMyCode":` should be set to false.

References: [Official VSCode Docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing#_debug-tests)

Answer (score 3):

If you are debuging a Jupyter Notebook, you may want to add to your `.vscode/settings.json`

```
  "jupyter.debugJustMyCode": false
```

See [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py#_jupyter-code-cells)