# Showing Full Call Stack when Python Debugging in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am using the Python debugger in VSCode to debug a Flask application. I have set a breakpoint. When I inspect the call stack, however, I see only my code rather than the full stack (which should include Flask, Werkzeug, etc). How to I configure / see the full call stack rather than just of the app?

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '' # breakpoint
```

yields:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Per [Visual Studio Code - Python debugging - Step into the code of external functions when executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53594900/visual-studio-code-python-debugging-step-into-the-code-of-external-functions), you need to add `"justMyCode": false` to your launch config.