# Setting maxBytes on RotatingFileHandler causes Formatter.format() to be called twice per record

Tags: python, logging

Can someone explain why setting `maxBytes` on `RotatingFileHandler` causes `DerivedFormatter.format()` to be called twice per log record? Ultimately, only 1 entry makes it to the log file, but I want to have some logic performed in `DerivedFormatter.format()` that shouldn't be done multiple times.

Example:

```
# Python 3.10.6
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

class DerivedFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def __init__(self, fmt=None, datefmt=None, style='%'):
        super().__init__(fmt, datefmt, style)

    def format(self, record):
        print("format_override called.")
        return super().format(record)


format = '%(asctime)s | %(levelname)-8s | %(filename)s | %(message)s'
log_file = "fubar.log"

Log = logging.getLogger()
Log.handlers.clear()
Log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

fhandler = RotatingFileHandler(log_file)
fhandler.maxBytes = 102400 # comment this line
fhandler.backupCount = 1
fhandler.setFormatter(DerivedFormatter(format))
Log.addHandler(fhandler)

Log.info("something happened")
```

When commenting out the the line where setting `fhandler.maxBytes`, `DerivedFormatter.format()` only gets called once.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you attached a debugger to this and examined the call chain? My bet is that it calls `format()` the first time to get the size of the message, doesn't store the formatted message, and then calls again during the write.

Comment: @MichaelRuth I am new to python, but I am running in debugger mode in vscode and the call stack for both .format() calls point to the same Log.info(). It doesn't give any insight as to what is happening in between. Is there a better way to debug this?

Comment: There should be several ways to step code: step, step over, step into mine, and step into. Step into is what you need to get into the library code. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53594900/visual-studio-code-python-debugging-step-into-the-code-of-external-functions) explains how to configure VSCode to do this.

Comment: Sorry, step out, not step. Step out is important because it helps you get out of the library code.

Comment: Ok great, this helps a lot! I can see the `format` method is being called if `maxBytes > 0` when it is checking `shouldRollover`. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is the "logic" supposed to do in `format()`? Is it a side-effect or something directly related to formatting a message? It would be better to move it out of `format()` if it's a side-effect, otherwise you can add a guard in `format()` so that the logic is executed only once per message.

Comment: Yes, I am guarding, but wasn't sure why it was happening. It all makes sense now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Michael Ruth for his comments and getting my debugger to give me more information and understand what is happening. `RotatingFileHandler.shouldRollover()` checks if `maxBytes > 0` and then calls `format()` to get the formatted message and check the length.

Thanks for the help Michael!