# How to skip certain files while debugging in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, gdb, vscode-debugger

I'm working with c++ and want to skip internals while debugging. A similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47556495/how-do-i-skip-external-code-when-debugging-in-vs-code) was asked before but solutions appears to be applicable for `node.js` only. Using `skipFiles` in `launch.json` I get:

```
Property skipFiles is not allowed.
```