# How do you `step in` only my variables using Visual Studio Code debugger?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm using Visual Studio Code, and I'm using the Javascript Debugger. My BIGGEST frustration is how to 'step in' only my variables, and not step in system .js files such as mongodb, node.js, etc.
I step through using the `F11` key, and it's great to see my variables take on values.

But, I can't figure out how to force evaluation of system .js files but not step in. PLEASE let me know how to accomplish this, if it can be. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I skip external code when debugging in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47556495/how-do-i-skip-external-code-when-debugging-in-vs-code)

Comment: I've seen that solution, but it doesn't work! It's so frustrating, it steps in to node files.