# How to debug external libraries in vscode-jupyter cell debugger?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, vscode-debugger

I am using VS Code with `#%%` in the python files which allows me to execute cells in the interactive console. It also allows me to debug cells. However, it doesn't allow me to debug external libraries while debugging a cell. I already set the flag `just_my_code` to `false` in the *launch.json* file. This works fine when using the normal debugger, but not when using the cell debugger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution, turns out that there is a field in the settings for this purpose.
We should add `jupyter.debugJustMyCode": false` to settings.json.

Comment: Did you do anything else? I toggled that setting both globally and in my workspace but it didn't work :'(

Comment: Seems from this comment that they are working on a bug related to this: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/8146